# Retrieving Specific data from firebase realtime database to text view

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Snapshot of firebase data collection]

When the user searches for the plant by name. I want to extract that data from the database. For e.g. when the user searches for Sunflower My app should display Price for that specific flower to Text View. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
DatabaseReference readDb = db.getReference("Your Chanel Name");
    readDb.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            list.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                list.add(messageSnapshot.getKey());
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

Put your data in a list. and use the following code when you search

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

You can also get the value of the item you clicked on.

```
final String value = adapter.getItem(position);
```